# Comparing romanian diacritics

Tags: sql-server, char, collation

I am working with romanian accented characters (diacritics) with Romanian_100_CI_AS collation.
Trying to select something regardless accented chars give me an unexpected result like this one:

```
IF N'tandarei' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = N'Țăndărei' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
SELECT 'Values are the same'
ELSE
SELECT 'Values are different'
```

returns

**Values are different**

"Țăndărei" is in a column with Romanian_100_CI_AS

what am I missing?

Comment: Latin1_General_100_CI_AI ?

Comment: @lptr
Uau! Indeed with Latin1_General_100_CI_AI works... I definitively don't understand what are the meanings of the collation codes. Thank you!

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand 
Ț is T in Latin1

Comment: `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI` only works because it simply doesn't recognize *any* diacritics, along with a bunch of other language-specific characters. If `Romanian_100_CI_AI` thinks they are different then they probably are. In this case `Țț` and `Tt` are actually different letters in Romanian, as shown [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_alphabet). It's not simply diacritics, it's a different character altogether. Same with `Ăă`. See fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=259ec4f5da2f2f674e28bb34a68caad4

Comment: Wikipedia says "strictly speaking these letters function as basic glyphs in their own right rather than letters with diacritical marks, but they are often referred to as the latter. "